# Integral of an angle that depends on a view

Tags: integration, geometry, trigonometry, definite-integrals, vectors

**The problem**

There are two lines: $l_1$ and $l_2$. For any point $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we can calculate an angle between a plane that contains $p$ and $l_1$, and a plane that contains $p$ and $l_2$. Let's call this angle $A(p)$. Now what I need is to find a formula for $A(D)$, where $D$ is a planar figure contained by two lines and a
hyperbola. This needs to be implemented in a real-time computer application, so the formula has to be simple in terms of computational complexity. However, I haven't found any solution at all so far, so let's say the formula complexity is not that important for now.

**What I have so far**

We can always transform the system in a way, that the area $D$ is laying on the $XOY$ plane (so every point that belongs to $D$ will have coordinates
 $[x,y,0]$). Let's describe input lines $l_1$ and $l_2$ as two pairs of a point and a unit direction vector:
$$l_1: [a,b,c] + t[d,e,f]$$
$$l_2: [g,h,i] + u[j,k,l]$$
$$\text{where}: t, u \in \mathbb R$$
$A([x,y,z])$ equals to the angle between planes normals, and the normals can be found using cross product. If we normalize the vectors (dividing by their lengths), the angle can be retrieved by "reversing" the dot product with arcus cosinus:
$$\begin{align}A([x,y,0]) & = \operatorname{acos}\left(\frac{\left[x - a,y - b, -c\right] \times [d,e,f]}{\sqrt{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + c^2}} \circ \frac{[x - g, y - h, -i] \times [j, k, l]}{\sqrt{(x - g)^2 + (y - h)^2 + i^2}}\right) \\
& = \operatorname{acos} \left( \frac{\left((x - a)(x - g) + (y - b)(y - h) + ci \right) (dj + ek + fl) - \left((x - a)j + (y - b)k\right)\left((x - g)d + (y - h)e\right)}{\sqrt{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + c^2}\sqrt{(x - g)^2 + (y - h)^2 + i^2}} \right)\end{align}$$

To find the formula for $A(D)$ we simply need to integrate $A([x,y,0])$ over $D$:
$$\iint_D {A(x,y,0) \ \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}y}$$

I have no ideas of how to solve manually even the first, internal integral and the only CAS I have is Derive 6 - I had entered this integral and left computer running non-stop. After 4 days of
 nothing, I turned it off... And that's where I got so far.

I would appreciate any help on solving this problem.

Comment: 1) How do you decide between the two candidate angles between planes  ($> \pi/2$ or $\leq \pi/2$ ?). If you choose systematicaly the second option, do you really need to integrate angles instead of their cosine, which would be simpler ? 2) **Don't await an exact solution.** But happily there are axcellent numerical approximation methods; 3) What is the global objective of  the computation of your integral?

Comment: Thanks for interest JeanMarie. The practical problem that stand behind this is much more complicated and involves calculation of a spherical excess of some kind, which in turn requires to sum of all angles of a spherical triangle on a unit sphere (I will post the whole problem, if I won't find any solution to this partial problem). As for numerical approximations - any stable, easy in term of computational complexity algorithm is desired - I just don't know how to start...

Comment: It might be helpful in order we (hopefully) see some simplifications somewhere, for example by using differential geometry tools (curvature, etc...). But you didn't answer my question 1) about the dihedral angle of 2 planes...

Comment: The problem is constructed in a way that the angle is always chosen systematicaly (are of $D$ and lines $l_1$ and $l_2$). If that simplifies anything then you can assume second option all the time.

Comment: In general: this is a part of a rendering equation that belongs to a real-time 3D graphics engine. I'm calculating occludance of polygons seen from another polygon (well, both are little curvy - as I already mentioned,
 the second polygon has an edge defined by hyperbola). Calculating occludance seen from a point $p$ is just summing $A(p)$ for every pair of edges of all the occluders. It works well. What I'm heading to now, is to calculate "shadow value" for the whole polygon D, intead of every single point on it. And that's why I started to consider integrating over
 $D$ with $A(p)$.

Comment: I see. Now for your integral. You can consider numerical approx. formulas. You take the value of the function for, say 20 well chosen points, enter these values into a formula and get a result that is with an error $10^{-2}$ or less. Is it enough ? For a hundred points, the error would be say $10^{-5}$, etc...

Comment: Sorry but for me it is almost midnight CET I have to go to bed.  We will discuss tomorrow.if you agree

Comment: No problem at all. What I think I need to mention, is that I previously solved analogical problem in the R2 - at first I encountered some difficulties,
but two things helped significantly: having some kind of reference hyperplane and eliminating the square root from denominator. I feel that some kind of similar
"tricks" need to be applied to the 3D variant, and that's why I strongly suggest that **finding another formula for A(p)** might be the clue.

Comment: Some thoughts 1) You can assume WLOG that $c=i=0$ (unless one of the lines is parallel to the xOy plane). It simplifies a little your expression. 2) Have you tried plotting the "level contours" A[x,y,0]=constant ? If yes, what do they look like ? 3) Have you tried to involve in your calculation the shortest distance line segment between the 2 lines  4) You can "sweep" your integration area along adapted lines ; there is a coordinate system for lines that is worth looking at: the Plücker coordinates.

Comment: Maybe take a reference plane (with the meaning it has in your "answer") say $R$, including the line segment S of shortest distance between the lines in such a way, for example that the angle between $\ell_1$ and $R$ is the same as the angle between $\ell_2$ and $R$ ?

Comment: 1) This is funny because I had the same way off thinking:) I found that if $l_1$ and $l_2$ are paralel to $OZ$ plane then $A(p) = \pi$, no matter the choose of $P$. So I dived the problem in 3: both lines paralel ($A(D)=\pi$), only one line paralel ($c=0$) and no lines paralel($c=0$, $i=0$). It did get rid of $c$ and $i$, but those are constant (and not even "bound" with $x$), so it didn't help much - at least for Derive.

Comment: 2) The output color is nearly flat then (on the whole polygon of D). In general, plot of $A(x,y,0)$ depends heavily on chosen lines (of course), but it's "shape" looks always like two asymetrical hills/extremum that more or less "try to merge into one spike". I hope it makes any sense. The shape of this 2d function looks like it could be successfully approximated with some trigonometry funcs.

Comment: 3) No, interesting. Could you expand your idea on how shortest distance might be involved in calculations? 4) I did use Plucker coordinates once in the past, but only to find orientations between skewed lines. In other words, I have a very limited knowledge of practical usages of Plucker coordinates. I have no idea how to use them here - can you please expand your comment? It sounds really interesting.

Comment: Can you give a **typical shape** of your domain $D$ bounded as you say by hyperbola and lines, but that makes still a great variety ! Maybe give equations.

Comment: Area D is the least problem, because off-screen renderings (i.e. not real-time) show, that approximating D with triangle, gives very satisfying results. So let's say for now, that D is always a planar triangle of vertices $[0,0]$, $[Q,0]$ and $[P, R]$ - without any hyperbola-like eges.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution, but it might inspire someone (who's better in geometry) to find the final answer. Previously, I solved similar problem in $\mathbb{R}^2$:

I needed to find occludance at point E, which was equal to the length of an arc on the unit circle (with center in E), created by projecting occluder on
that circle. To calculate length of the arc, I needed to find angle alpha (arc length = arc radius * arc angle = 1 * alpha):

[Click here for image (I have < 10 reputation points so I can't embed images yet...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjWwK.png)

So I needed to find an angle beetween vectors $[P_x - E_x, P_y - E_y]$ and $[K_x - E_x, K_y - E_y]$. At first, I did that using the dot product:
$$A(x,0) = \operatorname{acos}\left(\frac{\overline{P} - \overline{E}}{|\overline{P} - \overline{E}|} \circ \frac{\overline{K} - \overline{E}} {|\overline{K} - \overline{E}|}\right)$$
Let's say that this angle formula is the final occludance at point E (one still needs to perform some scaling by $2\pi$ afterwards, but that's not the point here and let's just skip it).

Now what I needed was to find occludance not at a single point E, but for some whole segment of coordinates $[0;0]$ - $[L;0]$. So I needed to integrate $A(x)$ with lower bound limit = $0$ and the higher one = $L$. Let's give one letter labels to every vector coordinate ($m = P_x$; $n = P_y$; $k = K_x$; $l = K_y$) and after separating them, the result is:

$$\int_0^L{\operatorname{acos}\left(\frac{(x - k)(x - m) + ln}{\sqrt{(x-k)^2+l^2}\sqrt{(x-m)^2+n^2}}\right)dx}$$

It wasn't that hard to solve this integral, but the final computational complexity was to high in practice.

Then I found, that **the whole problem can be solved without vector math, just bare trigonometry** as soon as possible. Instead of taking $A(x)$ from the dot product, I took one angle that was between $Y$ axis and $\overline{EK}$, and second one that was between $Y$ axis and $\overline{EP}$, and then summed them up (that's possible because tan() is continuous in range $(-\frac{\pi}{2} ; \frac{\pi}{2})$), or rather calculate the difference between them because tan is $0$ on Y axis, $>0$ on the left side and $<0$ on the right side:

[Click here for another image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNbZ7.png)

$\operatorname{tan}(\operatorname{FirstAngle}) = \frac{k}{l}$, so $\operatorname{atan}(\frac{k}{l}) = \operatorname{FirstAngle}$. Analogicaly we can get the SecondAngle. Now our unit circle moves on $X$ axis from $0$ to $L$, so we need to adjust coordinates $k$ and $m$ by $L$. And that's how I got to **a much better formula**:
$$\int_0^L{\left(\operatorname{arctan}\left(\frac{k - x}{l}\right)-\operatorname{arctan}\left(\frac{m - x}{n}\right)\right)dx}$$

These two arcus tangens integrals are extremely simple to solve and their solutions are very easy in terms of comutational complexity.
Like I said in some comment above: **having some kind of reference hyperplane (in this case $Y$ axis) and eliminating the square root from denominator were the "tricks" to success. I feel that similar "tricks" need to be apply in the 3D variant, but I can't find them**.

Comment: I have worked on the subject (as you can see it by a partial presentation with an "all-vectorial" solution) and a formula for the total angle, but I have had not time enough to complete it. I prefered to erase it for the moment (although I will undelete it later on) because it contains errors. It does not prevent you to have a look at it...

Comment: You should leave your answer, even if it had errors within. Mine "answer" is also not a solution, but I posted it to give potential inspiration to others. Your anwer was giving me inspiration, but now it's gone:( Maybe it's about reputation points, I don't know. I can't see it now. Anyway... still hoping to get your real answer (now even more, than before).

Comment: Yes, I have undeleted my answer, corrected a certain number of things (check my computations!). I realized that my error was in adding 2 angles in 3D that weren't in the same plane ! But the new thing I bring is a "totally vectorial" way to cope with the issue. In particular, the cross product $N_1 \times N_2$ should give interesting results...

Comment: Yes, thsese angles seems to be interdependent. I'm pretty sure right now that there is no common, constant, reference hyperplane, unfortunatelly. But there's still hope:) I'm going to post my idea soon.

Answer (score 1):

I will refer constantly to the graphical representation at the bottom. It gathers the main ideas together with notations used hereafter.

One can see that reference axes are such that the $x$ axis is directed by the shortest distance segment and $y$ and $z$ axis have been chosen in such a way that the angles made by lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ are symmetrical with respect to plane $x0y$.

Consider a generic point $M_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. Let us call (P) the plane (in green on the figure) with equation $x=x_0$. In plane (P), "moving" from $Q_0(x_0,0,0)$ to $M_0(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ can be decomposed into a red "move" and a blue "move". In the red move, the first plane doesn't change ; in the blue move the second plane doesn't change.

Let $c=\cos(\alpha)$ and $s=\sin(\alpha)$, with $u_1=(0,c,s)$ and $u_2=(0,-c,s)$ (unit vectors).

Let $\vec{i}$ be the unit directing vector of $x$ axis.

An immediate computation gives

$$\tag{1}c_1=\dfrac{z_0c+y_0s}{2sc} \ \ \text{and} \ \ c_2=\dfrac{z_0c-y_0s}{2sc}.$$

Thus, we can write:

$$\vec{Q_0P_0}=c_1\vec{u_2} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \vec{P_0M_0}=c_2\vec{u_1}.$$

Let us be more precise. The normal vector $N_2$ to the plane defined by $M_0$ and $L_2$ is:

$$N_2=\vec{u_2} \times \vec{A_2M_0} = \vec{u_2} \times (\vec{A_2Q_0}+\vec{Q_0P_0} + \vec{Q_0M_0})= $$

$$N_2=\vec{u_2} \times \vec{A_2Q_0}+ \vec{u_2} \times \vec{Q_0P_0} + \underbrace{ \vec{u_2} \times \vec{Q_0M_0}}_{0}$$

$$N_2=(a+x_0)\vec{u_2} \times \vec{i} +c_1\vec{u_2} \times \vec{u_1}$$

$$\tag{i}N_2=(x_0+a)\underbrace{\vec{u_2} \times \vec{i}}_{\text{unit vector}} -2c_1cs \ \vec{i}$$

For similar reasons, the normal vector $N_1$ to the plane defined by $M_0$ and $L_1$ is:

$$\tag{ii}N_1=(x_0-a) \vec{u_1} \times \vec{i} +2c_2cs \ \vec{i}$$

It suffices now to use formulas (i) and (ii) in order to have a vectorial expression of the looked for angle:

- either as the arcsine of the cross product $N_1/\|N_1\| \times N_2/\|N_2\|.$
- or as the arccosine of the dot product $N_1/\|N_1\| \bullet N_2/\|N_2\|.$

Remark 1: One could arrive at formulas (i) and (ii) by using the following analytical computations:

- the plane defined by $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and line $L_1$ has the following equation:

$$\begin{vmatrix}a & a & x_0 & x\\
    0 & c & y_0 & y\\
    0 & s & z_0 & z\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{vmatrix}=0 \iff acz_0 - acz + asy - asy_0 - cxz_0 + cx_0z + sxy_0 - sx_0y=0 $$

- the plane defined by $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and line $L_2$ has the following equation:

$$\begin{vmatrix}-a & -a & x_0 & x\\
    0 & -c & y_0 & y\\
    0 & s & z_0 & z\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{vmatrix}=0 \iff 
acz_0 - acz - asy + asy_0 + cxz_0 - cx_0z + sxy_0 - sx_0y=0$$

From these equations, it is easy to extract the normal vectors to these two planes:

$N_1=\begin{pmatrix}sy_0-cz_0\\as-sx_0\\cx_0-ac\end{pmatrix}=(-a+x_0)\begin{pmatrix}0\\c\\s\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+2c_1cs\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ which, using the expression of $c_1$ given in (1) is identical to (ii) (up to a global sign change).

and $N_2=\begin{pmatrix}sy_0+cz_0\\-as-sx_0\\-cx_0-ac\end{pmatrix}=(-a-x_0)\begin{pmatrix}0\\-c\\s\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+2c_2cs\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ which is identical to (i) (up to a global sign change).

2) It is interesting to note that, in formulas (i) and (ii), $2cs=sin(2\alpha)$.

[image]

Comment: Looks very promissing! I didn't get what you had on your mind in one of your previous comments about symetrical angles. But now, when I see it, all I can say is: it's briliant. I'll wait with some questions till you post your program, because it might give me answers I need. I look forward to your next post.

Comment: Oh, I think I need to address one thing, because it may be important: looking at your picture, the green plane is somewhere "between" lines $L_1$ and $L_2$. (I'm just taking it as a reference to tell you that) That's not the place where polygon D (the area of integration) would be laying typically. 100% of cases would be rather for D laying "further" on the X axis (from $O$) than $A_1$ point is, or to the other side - somewhere further from $O$ than $A_2$ is. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. One important thing that I have not said is that all along $x$ axis, the angle between the planes is constant (equal to $\pi-\alpha$) and can be seen as a reference angle. Besides, the issue of moving into green plane could also be phrased in a different manner by considering independent (integrated) moves in the 2 special planes containing this $x$ axis and $L_1$ (resp. $L_2$ ) with a subsequent sum of the corresponding two integrals. We are not far from your ideas.

Comment: I have added to my text the equations of the planes. I will work again on the subject, as I said...

Comment: I've been thinking about your method whole day long, I'm still not sure how to retrieve the final angle, but it has opened my mind to a different view on this problem for sure. There's one thing that keeps bothering me. You've mentioned that the angle between planes is constant along the $x$ axis and it's equal to $\pi - \alpha$. Shouldn't it be equal to $\pi - 2\alpha$ instead?

Comment: You're right, $\pi-2\alpha$.

Comment: can I kindly ask you to tell me, which program did you use to create that visualization/drawing above?

Comment: Not truly a program, PowerPoint.

Comment: I have added the normals' computation.

Comment: You are truly a Power Point master then!:) Are you sure you added normals' computation? I can't see them and the last edit date of your post still shows May 24 at 0:15.

Comment: I can't make your solution to work. Normals I've extracted:$$N_1=[sy_0-cz_0;as-sx_0;cx_0-ac]$$$$N_2=[sy_0+cz_0;-as-sx_0;-cx_0-ac]$$With these normals, calculation of $acos\left(\frac{N_1\circ N_2}{|N_1||N_2|}\right)$ is proper only for points laying on $OX$ axis ($[x_0;0;0]$). For every other point it's not even close to the real value of angle A(p)... Also I want to point out that we still have normalizations (so square roots) in denominators... Without them the formula is not working even for points on $OX$ axis.

Comment: Sorry for the normals. I had forgotten to save my modifications. Answer to your recent remark: The explanation is that it's not a single $acos$ but the sum of the **integrals** of **two different** $acos$. I am going to detail the solutions in some hours if possible.

Comment: And that's the most enigmatic puzzle in your promised answer:) I was working on a solution for last week (able to let 1-2 hours/day) and managed to find an extremely long formula, but without a single $\sqrt.$ in it. And still, it is a one, single, large $acos$. I don't see how to separate it in two, because the plane containing the final angle depends on both normals. In other words I still cannot find a common, constant, reference hyperplane. So I'm really, really looking forward to read your answer and understand how you've found it.

Comment: I've implemented your final formulas, unfortunatelly they don't work. Even the earlier formulas for normals, like $N_1=\begin{pmatrix}sy_0-cz_0\\as-sx_0\\cx_0-ac\end{pmatrix}$ are different from what they should look like, when real values are applied. I don't know where the error is. What I propose for now, is to abandon this solution, and this is because: 1.It's still a one single $acos$ or $asin$, thus it needs to be a one large integral in the end; 2.Still it needs to normalize normals, thus it contains two square roots in the final denominator;

Comment: 3. I already have a better "solution", inspired on your transformation to shortest distance on $OX$ axis. This "solution" is not complete and your help would be much more desired there than here (I think). I'm going to post my new method within few days.